# What should I look at when it comes to security on web applications?

Tags: node.js, security, google-cloud-platform, cloud-hosting

I'm looking at setting up a NodeJS webserver on a GCP compute instance. What should I look into when it comes to security (such as DDOS and other attacks); I'm not really sure where to start. I'm exploring professional development, so advice, detailed articles and explanations are great.

Comment: npm helmet.   nginx reverse proxy server.

Comment: This is way too broad. You can do an entire degree on security, even a more specific area in security is covered by entire books.

Comment: Why to use a compute engine?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Because compute engine is what I know at the moment. Do you have a suggestion to use something else to run the site?

Comment: @GaborLengyel I have to start somewhere ha. I'm not looking at a whole degree worth, more of a basic understanding so I can start looking into it more. I don't know enough about it to be able to ask about a specific area, but knowing what areas there are will be a good start for me.

Comment: Have a look to serverless solution such as Cloud Run or App Engine. A lot of security concern are managed automatically by the platform and you have less work on your side!

Comment: I'll research more into that. Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere :)